# Как при вызове функции-члена передать возвращаемое значение из другой функции-члена C++

Tags: c++, классы, методы

***Здравствуйте!***

Я хочу сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Class {

public:

    int method1(int a) {

        //блок кода...

        return a;
    }

    int method2(int a) {

        //блок кода...

    }

};

int main() {

    Class c;

    c.method1(0);
    c.method2(a); //ВОТ ТУТ ПРОБЛЕМА!
                  //пишет, что переменная неинициализорвана,
                  //но она уже введена пользователем в method1()

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Как исправить это недоразумение?

*Заранее спасибо за ответ!*

Comment: [область видимости](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще один вариант:

```
class Class {
public:
    static int a;
    int method1() {

        //блок кода... например:
        a += 5;
        return a;
    }

    int method2(int k) {

        //блок кода...
        return k + method1();
    }
};
int Class::a = 0;

    int main()
    {    
        Class c;
        c.method1();   // 5
        c.method2(Class::a); //5 + 5 + 5
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Очень сильно помогли!

Answer (score 2):

```
int main() {

    Class c;
    c.method2(c.method1(0));

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Я так понимаю, что так.

Comment: Нет, тут Вы передаёте значение сами, но мне надо, чтобы это значение вводил пользователь и переменная, которая принимает введённое значение, передавалась в аргументы функции при её вызове из класса.

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что Вы хотели написать так

```
int a = c.method1(0);
c.method2(a);
```

или даже так

```
c.method2(c.method1(0));
```

Я думаю, что Вы много писали на скриптовых языках, где есть сквозные глобальные переменные. В Вашем случае, хоть две переменные a называются одинаково, с точки зрения компилятора это разные переменные и компилятор не может догадаться, что Вы  имели ввиду.